# pulumi times out importing gcp record set

Tags: pulumi

I have some dns records I'm trying to import with pulumi, and they fail somewhat bluntly with this error:

```
Diagnostics:
  gcp:dns:RecordSet (root/my.domain./NS):
    error: Preview failed: refreshing urn:pulumi:root::root::gcp:dns/recordSet:RecordSet::root/my.domain./NS: Error when reading or editing DNS Record Set "my.domain.": Get "https://www.googleapis.com/dns/v1beta2/projects/root-280012/managedZones/root/rrsets?alt=json&name=my.domain.&prettyPrint=false&type=NS": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
 
  pulumi:pulumi:Stack (root-root):
    error: preview failed
```

I'm just getting started with pulumi, so I have no real sense of whether this is a GCP-specific problem or more general with pulumi, so apologies if this is in the wrong place.

Is this just a case of increasing a timeout limit? Is this a problem with the cli? Why would this particular request timeout? (It times out every attempt)

Appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `customTimeouts`: https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/programming-model/#customtimeouts

When creating your resource, you can pass an options object as the last parameter. In that, you can add your customTimeouts configuration e.g. (for typescript):

```
{
    customTimeouts: {
        create: '5m',
        delete: '5m',
        update: '5m'
    }
})
```